# MongoDB Aggregation - How to convert time string to ISO format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

All documents in my collection are the same as this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6396c58284bfad036f960288"
  },
  "title": "This is a nice title.",
  "time": "3266 sec"
}
```

But I need to convert the `time` field like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6396c58284bfad036f960288"
  },
  "title": "This is a nice title.",
  "time": "PT3266S"
}
```

Comment: Is it always in the format `"<integer> sec"`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes

Comment: Then the given answer is correct. Instead of `$regexFind` you can also use `{ $first: { $split: [ "$time", " " ] } }` which might be little faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set the `time` field. With `$regexFind` to capture the matched group.
2. `$set` - Set the `time` field. With `$concat` to concat string with "PT", the first element of `time.captures` array and "S".

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      time: {
        $regexFind: {
          input: "$time",
          regex: "(\\d+) sec"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      time: {
        $concat: [
          "PT",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$time.captures",
              0
            ]
          },
          "S"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i8mlKD4Iinq)

---

Or you can combine both `$set` stages into one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      time: {
        $concat: [
          "PT",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $getField: {
                  field: "captures",
                  input: {
                    $regexFind: {
                      input: "$time",
                      regex: "(\\d+) sec"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          "S"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```